Тип речи содержится или представлен?

(26)В девяностые годы пресловутое бытие наотрез отказалось
определяться сознанием. (27)Оно вышло из-под контроля, стало на дыбы и
рухнуло на наше бедное сознание с его главным инструментом  — языком.
(28)Теперь, когда пыль, что называется, осела, вполне уместно оценить
возникшие в языке изменения и подумать, как нам с ними быть.

В ответах указано, что здесь "представлено рассуждение". Я не согласна: в предложениях 26-27 явное повествование, а не рассуждение, ведь излагаются события во временной последовательности. Кроме того, никаких маркеров рассуждения там нет.

Чтобы разобраться с типом речи, надо сначала определить тему текста и его основную мысль (главное высказывание).  Представленный текст не такой простой, разные могут быть решения.
Текст делится на две части: события тогда и понимание их сейчас. В первой части автор повествует о событиях, но они связаны с их последующим философским осмыслением. Есть известная формулировка Маркса: бытие определяет сознание. Но высказывание это симметричное, соотношение может меняться: что, чем, когда и в какой мере определяется.  (Формулировка актуальна и для нас, ведь идеология очень важна,  мы это хорошо видим.)
Язык — инструмент сознания, и  Лихачев уделял ему большое внимание даже в то относительно спокойное время. Но в девяностые годы жизнь резко изменилась, и в этот момент бытие заняло ведущую позицию по отношению к сознанию.
Дальнейший итог автор осмысляет как раз в конце текста: "бытие рухнуло на сознание", до неузнаваемости изменило язык. И что теперь с этим делать? Как навести хотя бы какой-то порядок в языке. Это уже не повествование, а именно рассуждение, связанное с основной темой. Возможно, это и есть главная мысль текста.
P. S. Впрочем, это мое личное мнение, на котором я не настаиваю — возможно, кто-то думает иначе.
Дополнение
Я имела в виду, что можно иначе определить тему и основную мысль текста.  От этого зависит вопрос о том, представлено или нет рассуждение в последних предложениях.
Текст сложен тем, что здесь представлены элементы всех трех типов речи.  В нем фиксируются три момента времени: время Лихачева, девяностые годы и современность. Переход от одного времени к другому – это повествование, но при этом дается описание каждого момента.
Элементы рассуждения появляются с предложения (17), а в предложениях 26 – 28 подводится итог размышлениям о состоянии русского языка и ставится задача: пока нет явных кризисных явлений в экономике, нужно оценить языковые изменения и дать им оценку.
Но в то же время эти предложения можно считать описанием  двух временных этапов с точки зрения языка. Тогда это повествование + описание + рассуждение.

Вы говорили о двух решениях. А какое второе?

Я дополнила текст по возможности.

Еще больше вы меня дополнением запутали((( Если ответить кратко, то  никакой иной ответ, кроме как "представлено рассуждение", не может быть принят? Стало быть, задание корректно?

Нашла такую информацию:  Подводный камень №3
Между словами «содержится» и «представлено», которые используются в формулировках, есть разница! Надо её знать! Слово «содержится» указывает на то, что в предложении могут быть и другие типы речи. Например, описание может содержаться в повествовательном тексте. Или в рассуждении содержится повествование. Слово «представлено» обозначает, что в предложении есть только указанный тип речи. Другого быть не может! // Я считаю, что рассуждение содержится, так  там есть и другие типы речи (повествование и описание) .  https://dzen.ru/a/ZFd1emtsmRL65z_o

Но, может, составителям виднее)  // Я не знала этой разницы, казуистика какая-то)) Хорошо, если школьники в курсе.

Ок. Спасибо вам.
